# Converstion of HexaDecimal string to normal string

Tags: java, string, hex

In one of my application i have converted a string to hexadecimal value and i have stored the hexadecimal value in a file.
later i am retrieving the values from the file as it is in hexadecimal value can you suggest me how to make it to a normal string so that i can have the application more easy to built

Comment: What is the hexadecimal value of a string? Or is this a decimal number in string form?

Comment: You want this : string -> hexadecimal -> string ?  Can you give examples to make your question more clear?

Comment: Please show how you have converted the String so that we can tell you how to reverse that.

Answer (score 0):

well, assuming you converted each char to a hexidecimal string and wrote it, you could recover each char with `char c = Integer.parseInt(hexCharStr, 16)`.  then you put all the chars in a char[] and construct a String using `new String(charArr)`.